# Mysql Query to select duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `Player` in my database, it looks like this

```
 id    placex    placey    wealth    strenght    goalx    goaly 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------    
  1     500        20       3335      2500      500      440 
  2     500        20       777      2000        20      500 
  3      20       500       1000      2000      500       20 
  4     500       440       1000      2000       20       20
```

I need a query that would display id and wealth on a condition that players a located in the same location so there should be a duplicates of placex, placey for different players

In this table we would have player with id 1 and player with id 2 in the same place, I wrote this

```
SELECT 
    id, placex, placey, wealth 
FROM 
    Player 
WHERE 
    placex IN (SELECT placex FROM Player HAVING COUNT(id) > 1);
```

and I get this as output

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | placex | placey | wealth |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |    500 |     20 |   3335 |
|  2 |    500 |     20 |    777 |
|  4 |    500 |    440 |   1000 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

I need to eliminate player with id 4, so how do i modify my query to include also dups of placey

I expect to get this

```
| id | placex | placey | wealth |
   1   500        20      3335
   2   500        20       777
```

Comment: what is output result you expected?

Comment: i expect to get same output as i got with quary i wrote except without last row, so there should be no player with id 4 there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RUN this and let me know your result:

```
SELECT A.id, A.placex, A.placey, A.wealth
FROM Player A,
     ( SELECT  placex, placey
       FROM Player
       GROUP BY placex, placey
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) B
WHERE A.placex = B.placeX
AND A.placey = B.placey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id, wealth From Player 
inner Join (
Select PlaceX, PlaceY From Player Having(count(id) > 1) Occupied
On Occupied.PlaceX = Player.PlaceX and Occupied.PlaceY = Player.PlaceY
```

Always look at join before sub query gives you way more options.

Comment: My school server wont let me use occupied, gives me an error><

Comment: Um change occupied to B then. Tend to make my aliases sort of meaningful, but as long as they are unique to the query, doesn't matter waht they are, as demonstrated by the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id,placex,placey,wealth FROM player WHERE placey IN(
SELECT  placey FROM Player
GROUP BY placey 
HAVING COUNT(placey)>1)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5953e/6)

Comment: @user2977404 Its the same thing as Loc solution but his is faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.wealth
FROM Player AS p1
INNER JOIN Player AS p2
ON (p1.id <> p2.id AND p1.PlaceX = p2.PlaceX AND p1.PlaceY = p3.PlaceY)
GROUP BY p1.id
```

You should also add an index to index both PlaceX and PlaceY together.